Does the MWI have too much "baggage"?
Here I am talking about the popularised version of the Many Worlds Interpretation, with literally many parallel worlds, rather than the modern version that only wants to talk about the unitary evolution of the universal wavefunction and seems to want to distance itself from the idea of whole universes branching off.
Consider this set up of the quantum bomb thought experiment. There is Mach Zehnder interferometer with lower path that has a bomb. The bomb is actually a T tube that will let a photon pass straight through if there is no mirror and will deflect a photon to a detector if there is a mirror present. The detector (B) triggers a bomb if a photon is deflected into the detector. While this experiment is often described as counterfactual detection of whether the bomb is dud or not, it is actually the counterfactual detection of the presence of a mirror in the T tube.

In the classical interpretation of a Mach Zehnder interferometer (no bomb), a single photon entering the the apparatus follows both paths in a superposition and interferes with itself at the final beam splitter and always goes to a particular final detector (C). If there is an obstacle in either path, the photon cannot interfere with itself and if the photon follows the path with no obstruction, the photon triggers one the two final detectors (C or D) with equal probability.
In the illustrated bomb detector set up, the photon may be detected at one of the three detectors as follows:
B) The photon followed the lower path and there was a mirror present and the bomb explodes.
C) There is no blue mirror present (counts as a dud bomb) and the photon follows both paths in a superposition and interferes with itself, resulting in destructive interference on the D path and constructive interference on the C path. This result is inconclusive because the photon may have followed the top path and in the absence of interference randomly went to C or D, so a detection at C is possible, if there is a dud bomb or a live bomb.
D) This indicates the photon must have followed the top path and the superposition was destroyed by the mirror obstruction at B, thus giving a counterfactual measurement of the presence of the blue mirror (counts as counterfactual detection of a live bomb)
This is basically a quantum mirror detector and the bomb is just there for dramatic effect.
If instead of creating a parallel universe at the first half silvered mirror, why not just create a phantom copy of the photon? The phantom photon would takes the alternative path that the real photon did not take. If the phantom photon has the specific properties that it can only interact with the parent photon that it spawned from, the results of the quantum bomb detector can be duplicated without the need to create a parallel universe. The phantom photon also has the property that it is affected by the environment but it cannot affect the environment. For example a photon would be deflected normally by a mirror like a real photon, but it cannot activate a detector. In the bomb detector, if the real photon takes the upper path, the phantom photon would take the lower path. If there is no bomb present, it carries straight on along the lower path and interferes with real photon at the final half silvered mirror and so the the real photon is only detected at C. If there is a mirror in the T tube, the phantom photon is deflected by the mirror and is directed to the B detector but it cannot activate the B detector or the bomb. Since the phantom photon does not continue to the final half silvered mirror it cannot interfere with real photon and so the real photon randomly goes to detector C or D. If it goes to detector D it is a non destructive  confirmation that there is a live bomb (mirror) in the lower path even though the real photon did not take that path. The same results are achieved even though no parallel universes were created (or observers) in superposition with each other, so why do need all that extra baggage?
Now consider an excited atom of the source of a dual slit experiment. After any given time interval there is a probability that the excited atom emits a photon. In any given time interval a branching and creation of a parallel world, one for where the photon was emitted during that time interval and one for where it was not. this means there are branches where parallel branches are created before the actual emission of the photon. Why are all those parallel universe (and observers) necessary, when we all we need is parallel copies of the photon in this universe that are also emitted before the real photon is emitted. The parallel (phantom) photons behave like normal photons and spread out as waves and pass through both slits. When the real photon passes through a single slit, it could interact with all the the parallel photons, just as classical waves do and so an interreference pattern is produced, because the parallel photons interfere with the real parent photon.
So the question remains. Why do we need parallel copies of the entire universe, when the observations can be explained by parallel copies of just the photons?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

You seem to know that this is not the "real" many worlds interpretation but maybe the following will help.
A key feature which distinguishes MWI from other attempts to create an interpretation is that it takes the non-existence of separate wavefunctions at face value. If different systems in different labs really had individual wavefunctions in the strictest sense, then they would be non-interacting and continue to be non-interacting even after one was transported to the immediate vicinity of the other. All evidence we have of course suggests that interaction strengths fall off continuously without ever reaching zero and that interacting systems are described by a joint many-body wavefunction.
When you want to be pragmatic (but not so pragmatic that you forget about interpretations altogether), you can forget about this aspect of MWI that people like to emphasize. Modelling the mirror detector or double slit setup in the approximation that it is isolated, you don't need to talk about the set of all possible outcomes for everything (worlds) as the domain where the wavefunction takes values. Just the set of all possible outcomes for that one experiment. But a key question remains... are you part of that experiment?
MWI takes the view that we are indeed part of it. Just as the joint wavefunction describing two labs unitarily evolves into something with more and more correlations as they are brought closer together, so it is with human observers. The state of your brain does not start off having correlations with a tabletop experiment before you look at it. But the wavefunction after you look at it, while still having support on many experiment states and many brain states, will no longer have support on states where the two disagree. To discuss this phenomenon while forgetting about the rest of "the world", you still need the system to include more than what's on the optical table. And this is the aspect of MWI which really flies in the face of those who wish to claim that collapse is part of objective reality.
